# I am using python-weka-wrapper and I am not able to load any dataset from weka in Command prompt or IDLE

Tags: python-2.7

It throws me an error related to javabridge .How do I get through this and load the dataset?

```
>>> import weka.core.jvm as jvm
>>> jvm.start()  
>>> data_dir="C:/Program Files/Weka-3-6/data"
>>> from weka.core.converters import Loader
>>> loader = Loader(classname="weka.core.converters.ArffLoader")
>>> data = loader.load_file(data_dir + "iris.arff")
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.io.IOException: No source has been specified
at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.getDataSet(ArffLoader.java:1226)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\weka\core\converters.py", line 82, in load
_file
return Instances(javabridge.call(self.jobject, "getDataSet", "()Lweka/core/I
nstances;"))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\javabridge\jutil.py", line 855, in call
result = fn(*nice_args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\javabridge\jutil.py", line 822, in fn
raise JavaException(x)
javabridge.jutil.JavaException: No source has been specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data_dir` path has no trailing slash. When concatenating it with `iris.arff`, you will get `C:/Program Files/Weka-3-6/datairis.arff`, which apparently doesn't exist (`No source has been specified`).